# Search dictionary values for keywords in string

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I am writing a little "quiz" game as an exercise. I am storing questions in a dictionary. What I would like to do is be able to prompt for keywords to search for, and then do a lookup and print out *all* key/value pairs where values contain strings matching any of the keywords.

Is this something I could handle with regular expressions and a `for` loop? I was able to find some posts telling how to find keys based on exact values, but I am stumped as to how I would find values containing one or more keywords...

Here's what I have so far:

```
questions = {'1':What is the capital of Zimbabwe?,'2':What is the State Flower of California?, '3':Honolulu is located in which state?}
searchterms = raw_input("Enter some keywords to search")
#### I get stuck here
```

Update:
Forgot to mention that I am storing my dictionary of questions in a static pkl file using the pickle module.

I am loading the questions dictionary with this code:

```
def opendict():
    global questions
    pkl_file = open('questionslib.pkl', 'rb')
    questions = pickle.load(pkl_file)
    pkl_file.close()
```

Comment: With `all` and `any`?

Answer (score 6):

Loop over your key, value pairs using `iteritems()` on the dictionary, then check to see if your search is in the value:

```
questions = {'1':'What is the capital of Africa?','2':'What is the State Flower of California?', '3':'Honolulu is located in which state?'}
searchterms = raw_input("Enter some keywords to search")

for k, v in questions.iteritems():
    if searchterms in v: print k, v
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I tried your code a minute on its own (i.e. test.py) and it worked.  But if I try it in my quiz script it give the error ..."if searchterms in v: print k, v....TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable..."  I updated my original question because I forgot to say that I am storing my dictionary of questions in a .pkl static file using pickle.  Do you think that could be causing an issue with code?  See complete error below...

Comment: I think I figured it out :).  I had to wrap the v as string in the if statement.  Changed "if searchterms in v: print k, v" to "if searchterms in str(v): print k, v

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the dictionary and find the keys, with that you can store it in a list or show the question:

```
found = []
questions = {'1':What is the capital of Africa?,'2':What is the State Flower of California?, '3':Honolulu is located in which state?}
searchterms = raw_input("Enter some keywords to search")
for key, question in questions.iteritems():
    if len([x for x in search_terms.split() if question.find(x) > -1]):
        found.append(key)
        #print questions[key]
```

If the person can search for more then a term you can use list comprehension to see match one of the terms

PS: Africa is not a country :P

Answer (score 0):

you can use `for` loop and `in` operator for your requirement like -

```
def func(ques, keywords):
    res = []
    for k, q in ques.items():
        for keyword in keywords:
            if keyword in q.split(): # if you want to check whole words only,
                res.append((k,q))
    return res
questions = {'1':What is the capital of Africa?,'2':What is the State Flower of California?, '3':Honolulu is located in which state?}
searchterms = raw_input("Enter some keywords to search")
func(questions , keywords)
```